# Apply jQuery function on an 'el' of backbone.js to get the value of its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-views

I'm really new to backbone so the question may seem a bit naive. But I'm trying to figure out how to apply jQuery on an 'el' to get the value of an input.

Basically I have a form, and I want whenever the user makes some change to an input, the changed value is automatically saved to the model. But I'm having trouble getting the input value.

In my view, I have

```
  events : {
    'change input' : 'updateValue'
  }
```

And then I have the `updateValue` method like this:

```
  updateValue : function (e) {
    var input = $(this.el).find(input).val();
    console.log(input)
    this.model.updateValue(input);
  }
```

But my console is printing `undefined`. If I do `var input = this.el` then it can print the entire `el`, but when I try to do `find(input)` it says that it doesn't support that method. I've also tried `this.$el` and that doesn't work either.

So I'm wondering what's the correct way to find the input value, and wonder if this is the correct way to auto-save the form info. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Thanks to asawyer, I changed it to `var input = this.$('input').val()` and it worked like a charm.

This also works: `var input = $(e.currentTarget).val()`

And see the accepted answer below for some explanation. Thanks so much guys =)

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-dollar

Comment: Thanks @asawyer! I tried `var input = this.$("input").val();` and it worked.

Comment: Great! Write up your solution as an answer, and accept it! :)

Comment: You could also have done $('e.target') since in this case the input was the target element.

Comment: @robmisio Oh wow you are right. I didn't even notice it was an event handler.

Comment: @iBlue No don't edit, write an answer and accept it.

Comment: @robmisio seems that `var input = $('e.target')` is giving me an empty array...

Comment: @iBlue try `var input = $(e.currentTarget)`

Comment: that worked. `var input = $(e.currentTarget).val()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a jquery question actually. This is what your code should look like:

```
updateValue : function (e) {
  var input = this.$(":input").val();
  console.log(input)
  this.model.updateValue(input);
}
```

You were missing the "" around input, but I took the liberty of throwing in a few backbone/jquery tips as well.

The `this.$(":input")` method is a shortcut for `$(":input", this.el)` which looks for the jquery selector inside the view element, see [the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar). ":input" in this case matches all form inputs including textarea, select, etc, see [jQuery :input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).

Also, if you want to catch all inputs, not just the `<input>` element, try:

```
events : {
  'change :input' : 'updateValue'
}
```

Comment: Ah, took too long adding references to the answer, asawyer beat me to it :)

Comment: Lemme try yours and if it works I'll accept it =). Don't feel too comfortable accepting my own answer haha.